# How do I set legend element titles?

Tags: ggplot2

I am using code from this biostars post to get myself more acquainted with creating plots in ggplot. I am a bit stuck on setting the legend variables though

Is there a way to set the colour and control the number of breaks/dots in the legend (under numDEInCat)

```
term <-c("snoRNA binding", "preprophase band", "kinesin complex", "microtubule motor activity", "DNA replication")
fc <-runif(5, 1.00, 5.00)
padj_BH <-runif(5, 0.001, 0.05)
numDEInCat <-runif(5, 30, 300)

ggdata <- data.frame(term,fc,padj_BH,  numDEInCat)


gg1 <- ggplot(ggdata,
  aes(x = term, y = fc, size = numDEInCat, color = padj_BH)) +

  expand_limits(y = 1) +
  geom_point(shape = 16,inherit.aes = T) +
  scale_size(range = c(2.5,12.5)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low= "#ff0303",
                       high="#1e00b3")+  #colour for p value
  

  xlab('') + ylab('Fold Enrichment') + #lavel fold enrichment axis
  labs(
    title = "Gene Ontology all",
    subtitle = 'BH-adjusted',
    caption = '', 
    color="Adjusted P-value", #label the aacolor
    size="count") +  #label dot size



  theme_bw(base_size = 24) +
  theme(
    legend.position = 'right',
    legend.background = element_rect(),
    plot.title = element_text(angle = 0, size = 16, face = 'bold', vjust = 1),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(angle = 0, size = 14, face = 'bold', vjust = 1),
    plot.caption = element_text(angle = 0, size = 12, face = 'bold', vjust = 1),

    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, size = 12, face = 'bold', hjust = 1.10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, size = 12, face = 'bold', vjust = 0.5),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 12, face = 'bold'),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, face = 'bold'),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, face = 'bold'),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black'),

    #Legend
    legend.key = element_blank(), # removes the border
    legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"), # Sets overall area/size of the legend
    legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"), # Text size
    title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold")) +

  coord_flip()

gg1
```

[image: Gene ontology plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are `guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes(BLABLA)))` and `scale_size(breaks = c(BLABLA))`

```r
gg1 +
  guides(size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "red"))) + 
  scale_size(limits = c(1, 1000), breaks = c(10, 500, 1000))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>